# PYTHON TELEBOT. Выдаёт ошибку при запуске

Tags: python, telebot

Мой код:

```
from email import message

import telebot
import requests
import json
from SimpleQIWI import QApi
from time import sleep

token = "токен"         # https://qiwi.com/api
phone = "номер"

api = QApi(token=token, phone=phone)

api.start()  # Начинаем прием платежей

#print(api.balance)

bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут токен')

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard1.row('ТОВАРЫ', 'МОЙ КАБИНЕТ')
keyboard1.row('ПОДДЕРЖКА','ОПЛАТА И ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ')

keyboard2 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard2.row('Яблоко')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, parse_mode='HTML', text='<i>ДОБРО ПОЖАЛОВАТЬ!</i>', reply_markup=keyboard1)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def any_msg(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Йоу!')
    if message.text.lower() == 'я тебя люблю':
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAMOXwmvF3BiAkzri85_sdWyF2VoVJ0AAtIAA1advQoOBXI2dYM1ihoE')
    if message.text.lower() == 'лох':
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://i.imgur.com/hjgkDpR.jpg');
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пока, чмо')
    elif message.text == 'ТОВАРЫ':
        keyboard3 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        callback_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="хуй", callback_data="test")
        keyboard3.add(callback_button)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Выберите товар:\n", reply_markup=keyboard3)
    elif message.text == 'ПОДДЕРЖКА':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " Пишите админу, если возникнет какая-либо проблема - @sweetymarket_adm")


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    # Если сообщение из чата с ботом
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "test":
            price = 5  # Минимальное значение при котором счет будет считаться закрытым
            comment = api.bill(price)  # Создаем счет. Комментарий с которым должен быть платеж генерируется автоматически, но его можно задать
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Переведите %i рублей на счет %s с комментарием:" % (price, phone))
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, comment)
            while True:
                if api.check(comment):  # Проверяем статус
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Платёж получен!")
                    break
            print(api.balance)
            sleep(1)
            api.stop()  # Останавливаем прием платежей


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['sticker'])
def send_text(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'ID стикера, который вы отправили:\n'+ message.sticker.file_id)
    print(message.from_user)


bot.polling()
```

Ошибка консоли:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\shopscam\venv\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 257, in _async_loop
    target()
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\shopscam\venv\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 263, in _parse_payments
    payments = self.payments
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\shopscam\venv\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 60, in payments
    return self._get_payments()
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\shopscam\venv\lib\site-packages\SimpleQIWI\Session.py", line 164, in _get_payments
    data = response.json()
  File "C:\Users\probo\PycharmProjects\shopscam\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\Progs\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Похоже, что SimpleQIWI ожидает получить json, но получает что-то другое.

Comment: Отлаживайте. Ошибка тянется с пакета `SimpleQIWI`